# What transceiver can convert 10GBASE-KR or 10GBASE-KX4 to 10GBASE-T or 1000BASE-KX to 1GBASE-T?

Tags: networking, ethernet, 10gbethernet, sfp

A pci-e network card supports 1000BASE-KX, 10GBASE-KX4 and 10GBASE-KR on SFP connector, but the required mode for twisted pair support on RJ45 (8P8C connector) is 1G- or 10GBASE-T.

What type of transceivers can connect previous mentioned SFP+ related standards to 1000/10000BASE-T modes/protocols?

What are examples for block diagrams or datasheets, that describe this mode or protocol conversion in detail?
( Example for common type of these adapters: [fs](https://www.fs.com/uk/products/66613.html)
and a resource for general (but 2012) [transceiver internals](https://www.edn.com/design/communications-networking/4374010/Designing-with-10GBase-T-transceivers)
En-/Decoding: 8b/10b <=1GBit/s, 64B/65B >1Gbit/s <=5Gbit/s, 64b/66b >5Gbit/s =10Gbit/s )

Comment: I really do not understand the question. What do you mean by, "_SFP+ related modes_?" There is SFP for 1000Base-T and SFP+ for 10GBase-T. SFP/SFP+ is not limited to fiber.

Comment: That really doesn't make sense. The standard of 1000Base-T means that anything with 1000Base-T is compatible. If a standard is followed, then anything supporting that standard will work.

Comment: https://www.prolabs.com/assets/uploads/docs/INF-8074_SFP-Form-Factor.pdf page 21 shows pinout of 20 pins SFP+, but for backplane connectors it does not seem that there is a standardized pinout available.

Comment: An SFP/SFP+ is an active interface that plugs directly into a host (router, switch, PC, etc.). It provides the physical interface to the cabling. That physical interface can be one of a variety of copper or fiber ethernet standards. Thjat is the big reason for the SFP/SFP+: you can have a device with an SFP/SFP+ cage that can accept a variety of modules to meet the physical cabling requirements of a site. The 1000Base-K variant are meant for a backplane of the device, and have a distance limitation of 1 meter, which is fine for inside the host, but not for a cable plant.

Comment: @RonMaupin "They are compatible with the 10Gbase-T /5Gbase-T / 2.5Gbase-T / 1000base-T standards as specified in IEEE Standard 802." Almost an answer from inside this datasheet (vendor sopto) http://www.sopto.com.cn/upload/201907/25/201907251646537757.pdf Thx@all for support and engagement (question about availability of coding translation from host interface mediums in transceivers will be answered in comments, with knowledge appearing)

Comment: BTW, the 10Gbase-T SFP+ are typically quite expensive, it might be cheaper to go with a direct attached cable or use a NIC with RJ45 (and keep the SFP+ card for something else)

Comment: Every transceiver module (within standard of IEEE 802.ap, and 802.3an-2006) should be able to transmit packets from backplane and fibre network standard to 10GBASE-T, for e.g., if physical interfaces are provided. Public information has been updated since this question started. Answered at 
https://serverfault.com/questions/1064474/what-transceiver-modules-can-convert-10gbase-kr-or-10gbase-kx4-to-10gbase-t-or-1 , details on ‘physical layer model’ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Gigabit_Ethernet#Physical_layer_modules

Answer (score 1):

BASE-K is backplane Ethernet. Are you sure that NIC is intended to be cabled external to a chassis?

Plug both types of modules into a switch. A single module handles one medium type as fast as possible. Given the power and physical space restrictions, a module that talked over multiple mediums would be exotic. If it exists at all.

Comment: Thx. What I called "mode" Synopsys calls "(interconnect) medium interfaces". If i understand correctly (https://www.synopsys.com/designware-ip/technical-bulletin/ethernet-dwtb-q117.html) only 10Gbase-KX4 and 10Gbase-CX4 are compatible medium interfaces for connecting with common desktop 10Gbase-T or 1Gbase-T Rj45 PHYs if multi data rate capable (https://www.edn.com/design/communications-networking/4374010/Designing-with-10GBase-T-transceivers)? 10Gbase-KR is a different PHY, because of 64B/66B (R) coding. But what's the transceivers input medium interface and definition for that?

Comment: supplement: There is a block diagram that shows BASE-KX4 to BASE-T conversion for 8b10b coding. 10GBASE-SR to 10GBASE-T, 64b66b, is shown by a www <ethtool -m> log.